# How to convert nested loop in to recursion?

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion

I want to convert this nested loops in recursion. How do I achieve this?

```
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  for(let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    console.log(i,j);
  }
}
```

Comment: why? you wont even safe a line of code

Comment: I'm learning recursion so want to get more clear.

Comment: So many answers but no accepted or up voted....

Comment: @Endless, take one which is most versatile or what ever you like.

Comment: should not come from me but Dhruv

Comment: Yeah, I did Endless, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here another example of this recursion:

```
function loop(i,j,limitI,limitJ){
     if(i>=limitI) return;
     if(j>=limitJ) loop(i+1,0,limitI,limitJ);
     else{
       console.log(i,j);
       loop(i,j+1,limitI,limitJ)
     }
 }
loop(0,0,4,4);
```

Answer (score 3):

Generic function `product` calculates the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of its inputs - You can polyfill [Array.prototype.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) if it's not already in your environment

```js
Array.prototype.flatMap = function (f, context)
{
  return this.reduce ((acc, x) => acc.concat (f (x)), [])
}

const product = (first = [], ...rest) =>
{
  const loop = (comb, first, ...rest) =>
    rest.length === 0
      ? first.map (x => [ ...comb, x ])
      : first.flatMap (x => loop ([ ...comb, x ], ...rest))
  return loop ([], first, ...rest)
}

const suits =
  ['♤', '♡', '♧', '♢']

const ranks =
  ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']

for (const card of product (ranks, suits))
  console.log (card)

// [ 'A', '♤' ]
// [ 'A', '♡' ]
// [ 'A', '♧' ]
// [ 'A', '♢' ]
// [ '2', '♤' ]
// ...
// [ 'Q', '♧' ]
// [ 'K', '♤' ]
// [ 'K', '♡' ]
// [ 'K', '♧' ]
// [ 'K', '♢' ]
```

`product` is a variadic function (by use of a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)) which accepts 1 or more inputs

```
const range = (min = 0, max = 0) =>
  max < min
    ? []
    : [ min, ...range (min + 1, max) ]

const r =
  range (0, 2)

for (const comb of product (r, r, r))
  console.log (comb)

// [ 0, 0, 0 ]
// [ 0, 0, 1 ]
// [ 0, 0, 2 ]
// [ 0, 1, 0 ]
// ...
// [ 2, 1, 2 ]
// [ 2, 2, 0 ]
// [ 2, 2, 1 ]
// [ 2, 2, 2 ]
```

Using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), you can effectively create nested loops

```
for (const [ i, j ] of product (range (0, 5), range (0, 5)))
  console.log ("i %d, j %d", i, j)

// i 0, j 0
// i 0, j 1
// i 0, j 2
// i 0, j 3
// i 0, j 4
// i 0, j 5
// i 1, j 0
// ...
// i 4, j 5
// i 5, j 0
// i 5, j 1
// i 5, j 2
// i 5, j 3
// i 5, j 4
// i 5, j 5
```

`product` can also be written using [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function%2A) - below, we find all perfect [Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) under 20

```js
const product = function* (first, ...rest)
{
  const loop = function* (comb, first, ...rest)
  {
    if (rest.length === 0)
      for (const x of first)
        yield [ ...comb, x ]
    else
      for (const x of first)
        yield* loop ([ ...comb, x ], ...rest)
  }
  yield* loop ([], first, ...rest)
}

const range = (min = 0, max = 0) =>
  max < min
    ? []
    : [ min, ...range (min + 1, max) ]

const pythagTriple = (x, y, z) =>
  (x * x) + (y * y) === (z * z)

const solver = function* (max = 20)
{
  const N = range (1, max)
  for (const [ x, y, z ] of product (N, N, N))
    if (pythagTriple (x, y, z))
      yield [ x, y, z ]
}

console.log ('solutions:', Array.from (solver (20)))

// solutions:
// [ [ 3, 4, 5 ]
// , [ 4, 3, 5 ]
// , [ 5, 12, 13 ]
// , [ 6, 8, 10 ]
// , [ 8, 6, 10 ]
// , [ 8, 15, 17 ]
// , [ 9, 12, 15 ]
// , [ 12, 5, 13 ]
// , [ 12, 9, 15 ]
// , [ 12, 16, 20 ]
// , [ 15, 8, 17 ]
// , [ 16, 12, 20 ]
// ]
```

> I think using `map` (and `reduce`), while it allows for more complex recursive structures as you demonstrate, is actually an implicit `for` loop, which does not really answer the question on how to convert one into a recurrence. However, if you also defined a recursive `map` and `reduce`, then it would be OK :) -  גלעד ברקן

Your wish is my command :D

```js
const Empty =
  Symbol ()

const concat = (xs, ys) =>
  xs.concat (ys)
  
const append = (xs, x) =>
  concat (xs, [ x ])

const reduce = (f, acc = null, [ x = Empty, ...xs ]) =>
  x === Empty
    ? acc
    : reduce (f, f (acc, x), xs)

const mapReduce = (m, r) =>
  (acc, x) => r (acc, m (x))
    
const map = (f, xs = []) =>
  reduce (mapReduce (f, append), [], xs)
  
const flatMap = (f, xs = []) =>
  reduce (mapReduce (f, concat), [], xs)

const product = (first = [], ...rest) =>
{
  const loop = (comb, first, ...rest) =>
    rest.length === 0
      ? map (x => append (comb, x), first)
      : flatMap (x => loop (append (comb, x), ...rest), first)
  return loop ([], first, ...rest)
}

const suits =
  ['♤', '♡', '♧', '♢']

const ranks =
  ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']

for (const card of product (ranks, suits))
  console.log (card)

// same output as above
```

Comment: As brilliant as always :)

Comment: I think using `map` (and `reduce`), while it allows for more complex recursive structures as you demonstrate, is actually an implicit `for` loop, which does not really answer the question of how to convert one into a recurrence. However, if you also defined a recursive `map` and `reduce`, then it would be OK :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative.

This approach uses param initialization with comma operator *(just to make the code shorter)*.

Additionally, an operator param (callback) to execute any logic for each iteration.

```js
function loop(n, operator, i = 0, j = 0) { // Param initialization.
  if (j === n) (j = 0, i++); // Comma operator.
  if (i === n) return;

  operator(i, j);

  loop(n, operator, i, ++j);
}

loop(5, (i, j) => console.log(i, j));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could recurse by taking a depth and the values to iterate:

```
 function loop(start, end, depth, exit, ...args){
   for(let i = start; i < end; i++)
     depth ? loop(start, end, depth - 1, exit, ...args, i) : exit(...args, i);
 }
```

Usable as:

```
 loop(0, 5, 1, (i, j) => console.log(i, j))
```

The only real usecase would be deeper loops, e.g. [this one](http://jsbin.com/zopuhusice/edit?console)

---

If you want it completely without for:

```
  const range = (start, end, cb) =>
     (cb(start), start + 1 >= end || range (start + 1, end, cb));


 function loop(start, end, depth, exit, ...args){
   range(start, end, i => 
     depth ? loop(start, end, depth - 1, exit, ...args, i) : exit(...args, i));
 }
```

[Try it](http://jsbin.com/xohiselohi/1/edit?console)

Comment: I thought "converting a for loop into recursion" would mean the answer wouldn't include a for loop :)

Comment: Hes talking about a *nested for loop* ..  and i dont think that a loop with recursion is useful

Comment: I would agree regarding the usefulness. I think OP mentioned wanting to "get more clear" as he's learning. For my own part, I sometimes  like distraction into theory and away from what one might actually use at work :)

Comment: Nice! I like the new range function.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend this but you can do following(as it is difficult to read, for readability and understandability your code is best).

```js
function forLoop(i,j){
    if(j===0){
        if(i!==0)
          forLoop(i-1,4);
        console.log(i,j);
    }
    else{
        forLoop(i,j-1);
        console.log(i,j);
    }
}

forLoop(4,4);
```

Comment: Nice answer (+1) but you're hiding the constant, 4, inside the code body, which limits the length of the inner, `j`, loop. I made it a parameter in mine. I might actually prefer your initial logic catching only `j == 0`.

Comment: @גלעדברקן thank you for pointing out that, I will not edit my code as you have already done it(if I edit our answer will be match). But thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's my rendition:

```js
  function nested(i, j, maxI, maxJ) {
    if (i == maxI) return

    console.log(i, j)

    if (i < maxI) {
      ++j < maxJ ? nested(i, j, maxI, maxJ) : nested(++i, 0, maxI, maxJ)
    }
  }
  
  nested(0, 0, 5, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array for limit and values. The order is reversed, because of the incrementing of the lowest index first.

This works for an arbitrary count of nested loops and it allowes to use an arbitrary limit of the max values.

```js
function iter(limit, values = limit.map(_ => 0)) {
    console.log(values.join(' '));
    values = values.reduce((r, v, i) => {
        r[i] = (r[i] || 0) + v;
        if (r[i] >= limit[i]) {
            r[i] = 0;
            r[i + 1] = (r[i + 1] || 0) + 1;
        }
        return r;
    }, [1]);
    if (values.length > limit.length) {
        return;
    }
    iter(limit, values);
}

iter([2, 3]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an outline of a "[recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation)," where "each further term of the sequence ... is defined as a function of the preceding terms."

As you are probably aware, recursive functions usually have at least one base case, terminating the recursion, and at least one recursive call. To find a pattern, let's examine the sequence:

```
0,0
0,1
0,2
0,3
0,4
1,0
1,2
...
```

Our base case, where the call to a preceding parameter terminates, seems to be `0,0`. But this is also where the console logs begin, which means we first have to call all the way back to the base case. For convenience, let's assume the function expects positive parameters:

```
function f(i, j){
  if (i == 0 && j == 0){
    console.log(i,j);
    return;
  }
}
```

We can also notice that the outer loop, the `i`, stays constant for each cycle of `j`s:

```
function f(i, j){
  if (i == 0 && j == 0){
    console.log(i,j);
    return;
  }

  if (j == 0)
  // ... what happens here?
}
```

but here we get stuck. When `j` is greater than zero, we can determine that the current term came from `f(i, j - 1)`, but if `j` is zero in the current term, we have no way of formulating what it was in the preceding term. We need one more parameter:

```js
function f(i, j, jj){
  if (i == 0 && j == 0){
    console.log(i,j);
    return;
  }

  if (j == 0)
    f(i - 1, jj, jj);
  else
    f(i, j - 1, jj);
  
  console.log(i,j);
}

f(4,4,4);
```

Comment: I like this approach because it is backed up mathematically. However, I don't think that a single recursive function is equivalent to two nested loops.

Answer (score 1):

Transforming a nested for loop into its recursive counterpart is surprisingly hard. Good question!

You can transform every loop (without a stack) into a tail recursive algorithm. So this rule should hold for a nested loop too.

I think we need two distinct functions to get something equivalent to your two nested loops:

```js
const loop = ([i, j], [k, l]) => {
  const loop_ = (k_, l_) => {
    if (k_ >= l_) return;

    else {
      console.log(i, k_);
      loop_(k_ + 1, l_);
    }
  };

  if (i >= j) return;

  else {
    loop_(k, l);
    loop([i + 1, j], [k, l]);
  }
};

loop([0, 5], [0, 5]);
```

You have to pass ranges for both the out and the inner loop.

As you can see both recursive calls are in tail position. I think this is the closest equivalent we can get.

Comment: Cool, but doesn't it also assume we want the same range for each of the two loops?

Comment: Can you elaborate this?

Comment: Actually, I misunderstood what each parameter in your `loop` function is. I thought `n` was the start and `p` the end of the range (non-inclusive) for both loops we are converting. From experimenting, I found this isn't the case, but since what the parameters for your `loop` function are is an important part of the answer, I'll leave it to you to explain. They make different assumptions but still assume a certain expectation from the user.

Comment: @גלעדברקן `p` was a badly chosen name. It is often used to indicate predicates, but the predicate here is `===`. I Edited my answer.

Comment: Still unclear. What happens when you run `loop(3, 5)` and `loop(3,2)` and what would you expect? I was hoping you'd describe what each parameter in the `loop` function represents so the user can imagine in advance what will happen.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Yes, it didn't work with both of your examples. You have a keen eye for details, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

suggested solution

```
function recurse(arg1=0, arg2=0, cb) {

    if ( arg2 <= 5 ) {

        let _l = arg2++;

        if ( arg1 === 5 )
            return ;

        if ( ++_l === 6 ) {
            arg2 = 0;
            cb(arg1++, arg2);
            recurse(arg1, arg2, cb);
        } else {
            cb(arg1, arg2 - 1);
            recurse(arg1, arg2, cb);
        }

    }
}

recurse( 0 , 0 , (i,j) => console.log(i,j));
```